# Nullable and Unique is not working on laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I want to keep nullable and should be unique on My validation. Here is my code. can you please help me with this
in controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'class_teacher' => 'unique:sections',
]);
```

in migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->bigInteger('class_teacher')->unsigned()->nullable();
        ...

        $table->foreign('class_teacher')->references('id')->on('teachers');
    });
}
```

in blade

```
<select class="select2" name="class_teacher" id="teacher">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
        <option value="{{ $teacher->id }}" {{ old('class_teacher') == $teacher->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $teacher->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

here class_teacher is the foreign key from teachers table. but I want to keep nullable and unique Also for class teacher. but now In validate. it always sent errors. that `The class teacher has already been taken.`
can anyone help me to keep this validation that keep it unique and also nullable? please?

Comment: You get this on update?

Comment: no. I get this on create.

Comment: You are passing the `class_teacher` data, that's why it checked `unique`. You need to send `null` data

Comment: no, I didn't.........

Comment: dd the request...

Comment: please check now.. i add view in my question

Comment: from dd($request). i get this. ```"class_teacher" => null```

Comment: Its `dd($request->all());`

Comment: yes its from dd($request->all());

Comment: +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#52 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "kAfcon1CBP1pRYNsi0XDQuTiXQgHZrlUHLax7vFk"
      "section_name" => "B"
      "class_id" => "101"
      "class_teacher" => null
      "shift" => "Morning"
      "capacity" => null
    ]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your validation rule this way**

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'class_teacher' => 'sometimes|nullable|unique:sections',
]);
```